# What's the accessibility of Public Properties in a Private Class?

Tags: c#

If I have a class defined as below, what's the accessibility of the `Value` property within the private nested `Node` class?

```
public class LinkedList {
    private class Node {
        public int Value { get; set;}
        public Node Next { get; set;}
    }
}
```

Can anyone answer when possibly would you consider to do this? What's the implication of this class definition?

Comment: The public properties will be visible to the enclosing class (`LinkedList`), but not outside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd do this when `Node` is required to facilitate the `LinkedList` class in achieving its purpose/goals.

The implication of the class definition is that only the `LinkedList` class can create instances of `Node`.

Of course, `LinkedList` can also see the public properties of those instances of `Node`, including the `Value` property.